# JAXB: list and element with the same name

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an XML like this.

```
<Node>
<a> </a>
    <metadata>
        <metadata>
            <id></id>
        </metadata>
        <metadata>
            <id></id>
        </metadata>
        <metadata>
            <id></id>
        </metadata>
    </metadata>
</Node>
```

where the name of the list is the same of its element. How Can I map this in JAXB?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Node {
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "metadata")
    List<Metadata> metadata;

    static class Metadata {
        @XmlElement
        String id;
    }
```